# Remainder when a binomial coefficient is divided by a prime

Tags: modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

I'm a beginner (started learning yesterday only) in modular arithmetic.

The question is to find the remainder when ${}^{72}C_{36}$ is divided 73 (where ${}^nC_r $ denotes ${n \choose k}$)

I know such problems can be answered by Lucas' theorem, but in this case, it's pointless.

I can't treat $(36!)^2$ as modular inverse (and using Wilson's identity) either because the number is huge. Same for Chinese remainder theorem.

And with the above 3 approaches, I'm out of options. No clue how to solve it, even the hint given isn't "good"   (and I can't even prove the "hint")

Hint: ${72 \choose 36}={73\choose 0} + {73 \choose 1} +\cdots + {73\choose 36}$

Everything about this question, including the hint, is just bizzare to me!
P. S. I don't want to use the hint (It's actually the complete solution)

And the hint is wrong.

Comment: Can you show that if $1\leq k \leq p-1$ and $p$ is prime that $p | \binom{p}{k}$?

Comment: By Luca's theorem? Yeah, it'll be obvious (since the unit digit in base p will always be greater unit digit of p in base p for any number less than p. I don't know of any other method (yet)

Comment: What does it mean if a number is prime? What are its divisors?

Comment: Is ${}^{72}C_{36} = \binom{72}{36}$?  (If so, the hint is nonsense)

Comment: @Brian Moehring, yes, obviously.

Comment: No, not by Luca's Theorem.  By noting that ${p \choose k} = \frac {p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ and noting that $p|p!$ but $p\not \mid k!(p-k)!$.

Comment: @Integrand, yeah, I get what you're trying to say, prime will always be there, that too just once. How does that help here( in ${72 \choose 36}$)?

Comment: @fleablood, yeah, I was typing that. But how's it helpful? I mean $ {72\choose36}=\frac{37}{73}{73\choose36}$ but that doesn't seem to help

Comment: "yes, obviously"  That's obnoxious.  Not all text use the same notation and it's not clear what the notation $^{72}C_{36}$ is supposed to mean.  And as the hint is not true its very unclear what $^{72}C_{36}$

Comment: Well if the hint is true then $73|{73\choose k}$ so the remainder of that sum in the hint is ....

Comment: @fleablood, well it was asked in test. So

Comment: "well it was asked in test. So..."  And are we all in the same class as you?  Did we all take the same test?

Comment: I meant, I can't do anything about the hint or the question. Besides,  in my place the C notation  is more popular

Comment: As unsolicited advice, purge the word "obviously" from your mathematical vocabulary.  It only served to ignore my point about the hint.  I had seen both notations previously, but it is wholly unusual to see them both in the same text, even moreso in the same line.

Comment: @Brian Moehring, I didn't see the edit. I'm more used to C notation but it's longer to type it that way. I'll edit it.

Comment: That and the hint is *utter* nonsense.....  Although If the hint *where* true the solution would be easy.  My and integrands solutions were not that obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the hint is nonsense but

I noticed the denominator of $(36!)(36!)$ made me think that then numbers $1$ to $36$ are equiv $-72$ througe $-37\pmod {73}$ so $(36!)(36!)\equiv (36!)(-37)*(-38)*...*(-72) \equiv 72!(-1)^{36}\pmod {37}$ which made me realize the following result:

for any prime $p$, because $\mathbb Z_p$ is a field and every non-zero equivalence as an inverse:

$ {p-1\choose \frac {p-1}2}=\frac {(p-1)!}{(\frac {p-1}2!)^2}\equiv $

$(p-1)!\frac 1{1*2*.....*\frac {p-1}2}\frac 1{\frac {p-1}2*....*2*1}\equiv $

$(p-1)!\frac 1{1*2*.....*\frac {p-1}2}\frac 1{(-\frac {p+1}2)*....*(-2)*(-1)*(-1)^{\frac {p-1}2}}\equiv $

$(p-1)!\frac 1{1*2*......*\frac {p-1}2*\frac {p+1}2*....*(p-2)(p-1)(-1)^{\frac {p-1}2}}\equiv $

$(p-1)!\frac 1{(p-1)!(-1)^{\frac {p-1}2}}\equiv(-1)^{\frac {p-1}2}\pmod p$.

So $ {72 \choose 36} \equiv (-1)^{36}\equiv 1 \pmod {73}$

Comment: Yeah, this is the intelligent way to use Wilson's Theorem.

Comment: Dont even need Wilson's theory.  Just that refering to inverses and division makes sense in $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Wow, took me a while to understand. Amazing solution. Thanks!

Comment: So actually, for any prime p, binomial coefficient of upper index p-1, the modulo is just $(-1)^{((p-1)-k)}$ for any valid lower index

Comment: I was generalizing this, and it came out to be $$ { p-r \choose k} = (-1)^{(p-k-2r+1)}\dfrac{\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{r-1} (k+i)}{(r-1)!}$$ for $r\ge2$

Comment: I want to confirm something though, it's possible to substitute the modulo of the number only because they're coprime, right?

Comment: I realised that there are more restrictions than they appear. $k<\frac{p-r}{2}$ but that's not a problem

Comment: "So actually, for any prime p, binomial coefficient of upper index p-1, the modulo is just"  Don't know about that.  If $k=(p-1-k)$ this works becase $k!(p-1-k)!$ is "kind of" the same thing as $p!$. Wheres if $k < \frac {p-1}2$ then $k!(p-1-k)!$ will "kind of" be $p!$ with a hunk taken out the middle... Oh! but then $\frac{p!}{k!(p-1-k)!}\equiv (-1)^{2(\frac {p-1}2-k)}\prod_{j=\frac {p-1}2-k}^{\frac {p-1}2+k} j\pmod p$.   ... I think.

Comment: Oh... I guess that's what you got too.....

Comment: I didn't understand anything at all. @fleablood.

Answer (score 10):

Just by the way, I think the hint was intended to alternate plus and minus:

${72 \choose 36}$ = ${73 \choose 0} - {73 \choose 1} + {73 \choose 2} - ... + {73 \choose 36}$

${\qquad\equiv 1} - 0 + 0 - ... + {0 \mod73}$
${\qquad\equiv 1\mod73}$

as ${73}$ divides into ${73 \choose 1}$, ${73 \choose 2}$, ... , ${73 \choose 36}$, but  not into ${73\choose 0}$.

... built on Jose Carlos Santos's answer, which he deleted.

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: I think RHS equals 0

Comment: ${73 \choose 0} - {73 \choose 1} + {73 \choose 2} - ... - {73 \choose 35} + {73 \choose 36}$ = ${72 \choose 0} - [{72 \choose 0} + {72 \choose 1}] + [{72 \choose 1} + {72 \choose 2}] - ... + [{72 \choose 35} + {72 \choose 36}]$ = ${72 \choose 36}$

Comment: ... using ${n+1 \choose r+1}$ = ${n \choose r} + {n \choose r+1}$

Comment: and 73 divides into ${73 \choose 1}$ , ${73 \choose 2} ...$ but not into ${73 \choose 0}$

Comment: Wow, thanks for correcting it!

Comment: Is there a way we can resolve that single coefficient into the whole series from scratch? I've been thinking (in my mind) about it since yesterday but it feels random.

Comment: just so you know.. his answer is deleted, so you may edit your answer too

Comment: Done.  Re your other question, I'm sure it's possible as the expansion works generally.

Answer (score 3):

Not a very insightful answer, but sometimes there's nothing wrong with getting your hands dirty.

Since $73$ is prime, by Wilson's Theorem $72!\equiv -1 \bmod 73$. Let's try and compute $(36!)^2\bmod 73$.

$$36! = 2^{34}×3^{17}×5^8×7^5×11^3×13^2×17^2×19×23×29×31 $$
$$
\equiv 55\times 24\times 2 \times 17 \times 17 \times 23\times 70 \times 19\times 23\times 29\times 31
$$
$$
\equiv 27
$$Then since $27^2 = 729\equiv -1$, we have $\binom{72}{36} \equiv -1/-1 =1$.

Comment: You actually calculated that? How long did it take approximately? I tried doing that (before having any knowledge of modular arithmetic, infact these type of questions motivated me to study modular arithmetic myself which is not taught)

Comment: About 5-10 minutes; it's a Saturday and I don't have too much better to do. Repeated squaring helps a lot, as well as cute tricks (for instance, $55\cdot 4 = 220\equiv 1$, $2^9 =512\equiv 1$, $3^6=726\equiv -1$) that speed things up.

Comment: There are many *very* intelligent users on this website, so I won't be surprised if someone finds a more clever solution.