# Solving ${255\choose 128} \mod 257$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

My first thought was to use Wilson's theorem to get rid of the numerator:
$$
\dfrac{255!}{128!\cdot 127!} \equiv \dfrac{1}{128!\cdot 127!} \mod 257
$$
But I'm stuck on how to find the inverses of the denominator. If $257$ wasn't prime I could try factoring it and solving a system of congruence. I also don't see a nice way to group the factorials by inverses.

Comment: Try finding the last three digits of the expression or $\pmod{}$ ${1000}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem

Comment: Follows easily using $\,128^2\equiv 1,\,$ by *Wilson reflection* in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modulo $257,$
$$128!\equiv\prod_{k=1}^{128}(257-k)=\frac{256!}{128!}$$
hence
$$\frac{255!}{128!127!}\equiv \frac{255!128!}{256!127!}=\frac{128}{256}=\frac12\equiv129.$$

Comment: Very nice! This is easier than using Lucas theorem.

Comment: Very elegant, I think this was the intended solution (it's from an old exam in a course where Lucas's theorem isn't introduced)

Comment: After that, [using Appoach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Cbinom%7Bp-1%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cleft(p-1%5Cright)%7D%7B2%7D%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Acongruent&p=1), I just found [some more or less duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3728205/386889).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: As you can see, I did look for dupes and there are none: only posts which, though related, are considered as such only by yourself.